# kernel32.lib accidentally deleted - VS 2012 Fix

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, linker, kernel32

I recently installed VS2012 on my home laptop to write some software for fun in my spare time. Here's the order in which the mishap happened:

1. Accidentally installed VS2012 for Windows 8 Apps. Realized that I actually wanted the Windows Desktop version.
2. Uninstall the above, install VS2012 for Windows Desktop.
3. Start writing software, everything is fine and compiles.
4. See random VS Folder that mentions Windows 8 on my start screen - permanently delete it from computer thinking it was related to #1.
5. My program no longer compiles, with the following common error:

error LNK1104: cannot open file 'kernel32.lib'

I searched my C-Drive to find the location of this file to try and diagnose the problem, except that it doesn't exist - I can't find it anywhere. I tried a fresh VS2012 install, and that was a bust - the same problem. I also tried to download the VS2012 SDK, but it won't install, insisting the VS2012 isn't installed, and that it's required.

What can I do!?

EDIT: I've tried to repair the install twice as well.

Comment: Can you try a repair install? From Programs & Features in Control Panel?

Comment: I've tried repairing the installation twice with no success. As far as the restore point goes, the laptop is fairly new, and unless Windows 8 does this automatically, I don't have any.

Comment: It sounds like whatever you deleted totally Gumped up the installation. Likely have to uninstall it and start over without the additional delete folder step.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling then installing the software. No. Not reinstall or repair.

Comment: Uninstalling and re-installing the software is the first thing that I tried. Then I tried repairing it, and that was a bust as well.

Comment: If restore point fails, you can end up reinstalling Windows (though, i have no idea how it could let you delete one of the core libraries!). At least, you will have a cleaner system :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After multiple re-installs, repairs, and SDK reinstalls, the only thing that worked was a full system restore.

Answer (score 0):

You need to (re-)install the Windows SDK. That includes everything you need to develop Windows apps, including the `lib` files for linking to system DLLs. You'll find the Windows 8 version for download [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/hh852363.aspx).

I have no idea why re-installing Visual Studio didn't work for you. It should include the Windows SDK, but maybe you're installing the wrong version. Not sure if Express versions include it, for example.

Note that the *Windows* SDK is not the same thing as the *Visual Studio* SDK. The SDK part means "Software Development Kit", so they're similar. But one is for developing software for *Windows*, while the other is for developing software for *Visual Studio* (like add-ins and extensions and whatnot). The Visual Studio SDK is not going to include `lib` files for system DLLs, though, so that's why it didn't work. And naturally it requires Visual Studio to be installed first.

Comment: Then you're not actually missing the lib file, the linker just can't find it. Check that your path has not been overwritten, and that your project settings from within Visual Studio are correctly set.

Comment: I searched my entire computer for it - I deleted the entire SDK folder, and reinstalling it yielded nothing. Weird, I know. Perhaps I somehow downloaded the wrong SDK again, but I doubt it. I checked all the linker directories and stuff - the problem was that if you went looking for those folders and directories, they just didn't exist.